# In what ways can data be store?

Tags: database, web-services

I was asked to write a report on different data storage types.
Data can be stored in

- Text files.
- Different possible data bases:
  Oracle db
  Microsoft SQL Server
  DB2
- MySql
- PostgreSql
- SqLite
- excel sheet.
- Microsoft access.
- Proprietary database.

  I was able to gather a little information on this, any help can be appreciated. Please!!
  In what ways can data be stored, so that it can be queried using a programming language and data can be extracted by using a programming language.

Answer (score 1):

The real answer is, any structure that persists between application sessions.  This includes flat files (text, csv, xml, etc.) and RDBMS (Relational Database Management Systems).

MySql/DB2/Oracle/SQL Server, these are all RDBMS'.  Excel sheet, text files, etc. these are flat files.

Each has their own place.  For high performance and a lot of Online Transaction Processing (OLTP) you'll want to go with a full-blown RDBMS.  For small data that isn't often written to, something like an XML file would suffice.

What you're asking is a gigantic topic that many devote a large portion of their professional careers with.  It's impossible to give you an all-encompassing lesson on these.

Comment: Let me put it in this way, if a buyer searches for an item in a hub(amazon), it retries information about the item from many sellers. Every seller has a specific data base for himself. So the hub retrieves information about the item queried by the buyer(client in this case or a user).I was asked a question on how a supplier can store the product details, so that, when queried by the user the hub should be able to retrieve information about the product....Can I call this a Web Services?..I am new to the terminology.